# Performance Testing concepts for QML application

Tags: performance, qt, testing, qml, performance-testing

I am working on performance testing and would like to know the concepts of Painting, Creating, Compiling, Binding, Signal Handling for better understanding of performance concepts, also can any one suggest how to measure the performance rendering time, currently its been done manually using a stop watch as the visual monitoring is the only way to measure rendering time of the QML applications.

Note: Application works on tablet like device where the Qt profilers do not work.